# Problem With Importing GLTF Version 1 in Unity for Using in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, gltf, 3d-model

I need to import some 3d GLTF model (version 1) which has these properties:

```
"asset": {
    "generator": "pv2gltf",
    "premultipliedAlpha": true,
    "profile": {
        "api": "WebGL",
        "version": "1.0.2"
    },
    "version": "1.0.1"
},
```

I have used some Plug ins from the Unity store such as Sketchfab, and GLTF from Khronos Group, but none of the above method could help me to import my model in Unity.  I should tell you that I can view the model by Visual Studio Code and Cesium online model Viewer.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might not be possible.  glTF 1.0 was a WebGL-only format.  All of the materials are defined by GLSL shaders written specifically for WebGL 1.0.  That's why glTF 2.0 was an extensive breaking change from 1.0, severing the dependency on WebGL and adding compatibility with desktops and a wide array of platforms and graphics APIs.

Comment: So what is “pv2gltf “ stand for ?  How can i make sure about the version of the file ? Could you help me find out to Convert it to readable model for unity ? ( for ex : .glb , obg,.fbx )

Comment: Unfortunately I've never heard of pv2gltf.  It could have been someone's in-house tool, there's no requirement that it was ever released publicly.  There is a project called [gltf-pipeline](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline) that might be able to upgrade glTF 1.0 to 2.0 files.

Comment: thanks , my model insists of 4 part : 1. GLTF 2. Bin  3& 4: GLSL format files , I Found that it has made By Vuforia Model Target Generator , The Version of my Model is GLTF 1 and Still i'm  not ablt to modify the GLTF file , I Should Try The way you told .